# Failed while trying to update my todos list

Tags: python

I'm expecting to view the list of todos I defined as a user while using the code script of my program, but don't able to append new todo to my list at my todos.txt file. Is there is a side effect that happened or there is a bug?

Below is my code script of todos program:

```
while True:
    User_action = input("Type add, show, edit, complete or exit: ")
    User_action = User_action.strip()

    if 'add' in User_action:
        todo = User_action[4:]

        with open("Files/todos.txt", "r") as file:
            todos = file.readlines()

        todos.append(todo)

    elif 'show' in User_action:

        with open("Files/todos.txt", "r") as file:
            todos = file.readlines()

        # new_todos = [item.strip('\n') for item in todos] - list comprehensive

        for index, item in enumerate(todos):
            item = item.strip('\n')
            row = f"{index + 1}-{item}"
            print(row)
```

While I am running the code at Pycharm, the following result is:

```
"C:\Python\App1- To do list\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Python\App1- To do list\Main.py" 
Type add, show, edit, complete or exit: add drink coffee
Type add, show, edit, complete or exit: show
1-learn Pythonclean the roombinge el dragon: return of a warrior
```

I am expecting to see todo drink coffee in my updated list but with no success. How can I see the new list?

Comment: you only read the file, but you never save anything new in the file. the action `add` should save the new list in the file once the new todo is appended to the list.

Comment: Yeah, you completely right... how do I expect to append new todo without writing him first? thanks, man:)

Comment: `if 'add' in User_action` isn't the best of ideas. What happens if I input "show address"?

Comment: I didn't copied the whole code, just the related to my problem. I have an 'else' condition for this cases: "command is not valid".